Is it possible to prefetch an endpoing using Workbox?
I'm creating a PWA app (Vite + React) and I'd like to fetch all necessary data once app is opened. I know it's possible to prefetch static assets like html, css, js and images but I would also like to make some fetch requests and cache them.
Is it possible?
I tried adding endpoint address to precacheAndRoute() directive, but it became text/html type
